# Save Dialog in Mobile Application using C#

Tags: c#, windows-mobile

Here is my code

```
     SaveFileDialog dialog = new SaveFileDialog();
      if (dialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
      {
         aspectRatioPictureBox1.Photo.Save(dialog.FileName,
          System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);
      }
      dialog.Dispose();
```

I want to save the file in mypictures folder defaultly with the name given by user

Answer (score 1):

Why use `SaveFileDialog` ? Prompt the user to provide file-name to save and save the file to `MyPictures` special folder with that file-name.

```
Environment.SpecialFolder special = Environment.SpecialFolder.MyPictures;
string MyPicturesLocation = Environment.GetFolderPath(special);

//prompt the user for file-name and save it to MyPicturesLocation here.
```